# WebRTC not working for VPN and non-VPN client

Tags: node.js, webrtc, node-webkit, nw.js, peerjs

Recently I wrote some screen-sharing application, which use Peer.js library (which use WebRTC) to share media content. Generally, after application starts it get uniq ID from PeerJSServer to current client. If both of clients into the VPN network, or both of clients is not in VPN network - all works perfectly. But if one client is into the VPN, and another client is not - connection doesn't established.
Who know - how can I fix this?
I will happy to get any help from you.

Comment: do you have TURN server set-up?

Comment: yes, I use my own TURN and STUN servers

Comment: check on the TURN server configurations, usually thats where the issue is